# leptonica build issue , does not include libtiff

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am working on tesseract engine . 
 Used red hat linux to build both leptonica and tesseract  .  On running tesseract getting following error.

```
[tesseract-ocr]$ tesseract address.png out1
Error in pixReadMemTiff: function not present
Error in pixReadMem: tiff: no pix returned
Error in pixaGenerateFontFromString: pix not made
Error in bmfCreate: font pixa not made
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.00.00alpha with Leptonica
Error in pixReadStreamPng: function not present
Error in pixReadStream: png: no pix returned
Error in pixRead: pix not read
Error during processing.
```

while searching on the net , i came to find that it is problem with leptonica build . and it is not built properly with ltiff . In fact in config.log which gets generated out of ./configure command . i can see following

```
configure:12538: checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff
configure:12564: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/lib64 conftest.c -ltiff -lm
    >&5
/bin/ld: cannot find -ltiff
```

However i see that libtiff is present in the system

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-35-131 lib]$ ldconfig -p | grep libtif
        libtiffxx.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libtiffxx.so.5
        libtiff.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libtiff.so.5
```

I tried pointing to /lib64 path , as per reference from leptonica site  [http://www.leptonica.com/source/README.html][1]
  *Finally, if you find that the installed programs are unable to link
  at runtime to the installed library, which is in /usr/local/lib,
  try to run configure in this way:
           LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib" ./configure
       which causes the compiler to pass those options through to the linker.*

changing LDFLAGS to point to /lib64 is also not working    
 `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/lib64" ./configure`

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install

```
apt-get install -y libtiff5-dev
```

Then install leptonica from source

```
git clone https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica.git leptonica
cd leptonica
./autobuild
./configure --with-libtiff
make -j
make install
```

And reinstall tesseract after that

Comment: this solved my question `Error in pixReadMemTiff: function not present
Error in pixReadMem: tiff: no pix returned
Error in pixaGenerateFontFromString: pix not made
Error in bmfCreate: font pixa not made`, thanks！